# Cant set two NSStrings into one UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I want to get

```
NSString * test1 = @"one";
 NSString * test2 = @"two";
```

to my UITextView. I wrote this:

```
  uitextview.text = (@"%@, %@",test1, test2 );
```

but the UITextView only gets the second NSString... Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing a format string into a method that doesn't accept format strings. A better way is to append one string to the other using [`stringByAppendingString`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:):

```
uitextview.text = [test1 stringByAppendingString:test2];
```

Comment: Thanks, now he writes onetwo, but how can I get a , between them?

Comment: See DyingCactus' example for that.

Answer (score 12):

You can also do this:

```
uitextview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", test1, test2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just write `@"%@ %@"` and expect it to be treated as a format string. It's just an ordinary NSString containing some weird characters. To have it used as a format string, you have to pass it to a method or function that will treat it as such. In this case, you want `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",test1, test2]`.